# Error parsing XML:not well-informed

Tags: android

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with the code I've written. It gives the following error in Eclipse: Error parsing XML:not well-informed(invalid-token). The error appears on the line marked in bold letters. I've tried everything that is in my knowledge to solve this issue. If someone could help it would be great.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
            **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#dc6800"> </TextView>
        <!-- Description label -->
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:id="@+id/description"> </TextView>
        <!-- Linear Layout for cost and price Cost:Rs.100 -->
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <!-- Cost Label -->
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
                android:text="Cost:"
                android:gravity="left" />
            <!-- Price Label -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:id="@+id/cost"
                android:gravity="left"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove the second linear layout. its not required. also use relative layout instead of many linear layouts

Comment: You are closing the first linear layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct XML.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#dc6800"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    <!-- Description label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac" >
    </TextView>
    <!-- Linear Layout for cost and price Cost:Rs.100 -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Cost Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Cost:"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!-- Price Label -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```